# What is the meaning of the string containing symbols and numbers that sometimes follows a reference to a Windows driver sys file?

Tags: audio, drivers, dll

In Voicemeeter (a virtual audio IO driver), I have the following string in my list of devices: `KS: @System32\drivers\bthhfenum.sys,#2;%1 Hands-Free AG Audio%0;(SRS-XB12)`. I'm not concerned that it's there: I'm merely curious about it (though I'm also curious why I have a `KS:SRS-XB12 Stereo`, which is "correctly" recognised and formatted, directly underneath).

The device is my Bluetooth speaker (a Sony SRS-XB12), but there are parts of this string that I don't understand. I've seen similar combinations of `#`, `%`, numbers etc. after driver sys files before and have never understood why.

I know that `KS` refers to kernel streaming audio. I'm not sure why there's an at symbol in front of the path to the driver (anyone else know?). Then, of course, is the path to the `bthhfenum.sys` file, which is evidently the driver binary. And then there's a string similar to a query string (I'd be surprised if this isn't also similar in function). It's also similar to strings I've seen after references to DLL files -- also comma separated. In the case of DLLs, this seems to be the name(s) of specific exported symbols/functions required by whatever is running the DLL (is this correct?)

Is there a proper name for a string like this?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, there seems to be a clue at the [end of this Remarks section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/bthhfpddi/ns-bthhfpddi-_bthhfp_descriptor#remarks)  Based on this info, I'm guessing `KS:` might be a handler that accepts a binary library `System32\drivers\bthhfenum.sys`, an exported API by index `#2`, and a format string specifier `%1 Hands-Free AG Audio%0;(SRS-XB12)` in order to generate a user-friendly string for the UI.

Comment: @leeharvey1 Sorry, I only just noticed that you had commented. That struct does match remarkably well with the sequence, doesn't it? I'm still not entirely sure why it's referenced this way in my application but that does help a lot! Thanks very much.